# Excerpts for Pages

Tags: page-template, excerpt

I inserted an excerpt into a Page using the "More" button in WP GUI.

I have a custom loop-page.php from which I want to display the excerpt. But it appears to be empty?

Is it possible to display excerpts from child pages?

```
$pageChildren = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order&hierarchical=0&child_of='.$post->ID);
if ( $pageChildren ) {
  foreach ( $pageChildren as $pageChild ) {
    echo '<p>And the title is: '. $pageChild->post_title.'</p>';
        print_r($pageChild);
        if (!empty($pageChild->post_excerpt)){
            echo '<p><a href="' . get_permalink($pageChild->ID) . '">' . $pageChild->post_excerpt.'</a> </p> ';
        }
        echo '<hr />';
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the "more" tag does not create an excerpt. It simply creates a "Read More" link when displaying the_content() on index pages.

Excerpts are created/displayed as follows:

To display an excerpt, your template file needs to call "the_excerpt()" rather than "the_content()". Note: you use the equivalent $post->post_excerpt, which should also work just fine.

The "the_excerpt()" template tag then displays the excerpt, which is created as follows:

1) By entering excerpt content into the "Excerpt" field on the Edit Post/Edit Page screen.
2) Automatically, based on number of characters, if no content is added to the "Excerpt" field.

EDIT:

Okay so I totally missed this at first. Only *Posts* have the "excerpt" field. *Pages* don't have the "excerpt" field. So, $post->post_excerpt will never be populated for Pages (I think).

Try running "setup_postdata( $pageChild )" inside your foreach loop, and then replacing "$pageChild->post_excerpt" with "get_the_excerpt()":

```
foreach ( $pageChildren as $pageChild ) {
    setup_postdata( $pageChild );
    echo '<p>And the title is: '. $pageChild->post_title.'</p>';
        print_r($pageChild);
            echo '<p><a href="' . get_permalink($pageChild->ID) . '">' . get_the_excerpt() .'</a> </p> ';
        echo '<hr />';
}
```

Does that work?

Comment: Hi Chip. I understand excerpts now, but I can't find where they are entered. I added a screenshot of what I see when editing a post. There doesn't appear to be an "excerpt" area. This is why I thought 'more' was 'excerpt'

Comment: I don't see the screenshot, but I suspect the issue is that the "Excerpt" field isn't enabled. From your Post Edit screen, click the "Screen Options" tab in the upper right-hand corner, and ensure that the checkbox for "Excerpt" is enabled (checked).

Comment: I guess my theme doesn't have excerpt built in. When I click screen options there is no checkbox or area for excerpt.

Comment: My mistake. Pages don't have $post->post_excerpt. I updated my answer with another suggested fix.

Comment: You can add excerpts to Pages like this (call this on init): `add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );`

Comment: @goldenapples - yes, that did add excerpt section to page editor. For others I added this call to top of functions.php. @chip the loop displays the entire post, not what is in the excerpt box. I am going to mess around and for a bit and try to sort it out.

Comment: Okay, so looks like the original code I was using does the trick as long as you use goldenapples excerpt addition bit. Sweet!